# StartupFeatures with karaf-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-karaf, karaf

I'm trying to create my own karaf distribution, right now i'm able to assembly my features without any problem, but i'm not being able to register them to the **startup.properties** using the recommended tag.

```
<startupFeature>foo</startupFeature> This will result in the feature bundles
being listed in startup.properties at the appropriate start level and the bundles
being copied into the "system" internal repository. You can use feature_name
or feature_name/feature_version formats.
```

When i use the tag i get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:4.0.5:assembly (default-cli) on project winthor-karaf: Unable to build assembly: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.ide
ntity=winthor-core-servico; type=karaf.feature; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=winthor-core-servico)(type=karaf.feature))" -> [Help 1]
```

And if i use the **installedFeatures** tag before the **startUpFeatures** tag, the error goes away, but the features bundles are not registered at the **startup.properties** file, so they won't start-up.

What i'm doing wrong?

---

Here is the relevant part of my pom:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
      <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.5</version>
      <type>kar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <classifier>features</classifier>
      <version>4.0.5</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <type>xml</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
      <classifier>features</classifier>
      <type>xml</type>
      <version>4.0.5</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>br.com.pcsist.winthor.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>winthor-core-features</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <classifier>features</classifier>
      <type>xml</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>br.com.pcsist.winthor.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>winthor-autenticacao-features</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <classifier>features</classifier>
      <type>xml</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
        <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <bootFeatures>
            <bootFeature>instance</bootFeature>
            <bootFeature>package</bootFeature>
            <bootFeature>log</bootFeature>
            <bootFeature>ssh</bootFeature>
            <bootFeature>aries-blueprint</bootFeature>
            <bootFeature>framework</bootFeature>
            <bootFeature>system</bootFeature>
            <bootFeature>feature</bootFeature>
            <bootFeature>shell</bootFeature>
            <bootFeature>management</bootFeature>
            <bootFeature>service</bootFeature>
            <bootFeature>jaas</bootFeature>
            <bootFeature>shell-compat</bootFeature>
            <bootFeature>deployer</bootFeature>
            <bootFeature>diagnostic</bootFeature>
            <bootFeature>wrap</bootFeature>
            <bootFeature>bundle</bootFeature>
            <bootFeature>config</bootFeature>
            <bootFeature>kar</bootFeature>
          </bootFeatures>
          <startupFeatures>
            <startupFeature>winthor-core-data</startupFeatur>
            <startupFeature>winthor-core-servico</startupFeature>
            <feature>winthor-autenticacao</feature>
          </startupFeatures>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: I had similar problem with custom distributions. Please try removing the scope runtime from the features deps... It looks like it goes against what it says in the docs here (https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/karaf/site/production/manual/latest-3.0.x/custom-distribution.html) but for me it worked!

Comment: Removing the runtime scope will change the dependencies to compile scope, and with that it seems that the plugin can't resolve some transient dependencies, i tried to manualy add the dependencies, without success.

eg: 

... Unable to resolve org.springframework.osgi.web/1.2.1: missing requirement ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved our problem using a different approach, we found out that the **startup.properties** bundles run **before** the bootFeatures, that wasn't clear in the documentation, so we created a simple kar with our core features and referenced it as a compile scope to the custom karaf distribution.

The remaining features were registered as runtime-scoped Boot Features and it worked like a charm.

And about the karaf-maven-plugin, it seems that the **startupfeatures** functionality is broken.